# Member access on shared_ptr to pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I have a class which needs to have a member reference to an abstract class interface that cannot be instantiated in the class constructor. I want this reference to be a shared pointer. Because I want the reference to be to an interface, and I cannot instantiate the object pointed to by the shared_ptr in my constructor, I have to make a shared_ptr to a pointer to an instance of the interface.

Now I want to use the member access operator-> on the shared_ptr, but this is quite ugly because I have to dereference the pointer every time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class IFace {
public:
    virtual ~IFace() {};
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class A : public IFace {
public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};
    virtual void doSomething() { std::cout << "Foo"; };
};

class B {
public:
    B() {};
    ~B() {};
    std::shared_ptr<IFace *> myA;
    void attachA(std::shared_ptr<IFace *> a) {
    this->myA = a;
    };

    void callDoSomethingFromIFace() {
    (*(this->myA))->doSomething();
    };
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    b.attachA(std::make_shared<A *>(&a));
    b.callDoSomethingFromIFace();
}
```

Is there a way to use the member access operator-> like so

```
this->myA->doSomething();
```

Instead of

```
(*(this->myA))->doSomething();
```

Comment: Object `a` is allocated with automatic storage duration, its ownership can not be shared anyhow. By creating an extra heap allocated pointer to this object you are just adding pointless overhead. If you need to a `shared_ptr` then you need to allocate this object on the heap (and make sure that interface has a virtual destructor).

Comment: Having a `shared_ptr` to a pointer does not make sense.

Comment: *"I cannot instantiate the object pointed to by the shared_ptr in my constructor, I have to make a shared_ptr to a pointer to an instance of the interface"* - What? I don't follow this logic at all

Comment: @UnholySheep Because the interface is an abstract class, a normal shared pointer will not compile because the interface does not have a constructor.

Comment: @DJohnson that's absolutely wrong - if the `std::shared_ptr` doesn't compile then the raw pointer wouldn't compile either

Comment: @DJohnson You simply need to store a pointer to a heap-allocated `A` class instance inside of `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @UnholySheep Okay try replacing `std::shared_ptr<IFace *> myA;` with `std::shared_ptr<IFace> myA;` and `IFace* myA; ` You will find out it actually does compile and work quite fine.

Comment: @VTT I need a pointer to the interface so I can replace A.

Comment: It is not clear why you want to use `std::shared_ptr<IFace *> myA` instead of `std::shared_ptr<IFace> myA`, especially because it compiles and works fine with `std::shared_ptr<IFace> myA`. You should explain why the code I have shown won't work for you.  You might have a fundamental misunderstanding of the concept of shared pointers and when to use them.

Comment: As far as I can see you lose any safety the `shared_ptr` provides by having it point to a raw pointer. You are keeping the raw pointer safe but it is still a raw pointer and it doesn't manage the thing it points to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you assume that `[...] because the interface is an abstract class, a normal shared pointer will not compile because the interface does not have a constructor.`

This works perfectly fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class IFace {
public:
    virtual ~IFace() {};
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

class A : public IFace {
public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};
    virtual void doSomething() { std::cout << "Foo"; };
};

class B {
public:
    B() {};
    ~B() {};
    std::shared_ptr<IFace> myA;
    void attachA(std::shared_ptr<IFace> a) {
    this->myA = a;
    };

    void callDoSomethingFromIFace() {
     this->myA->doSomething();
    };
};

int main() {
    B b;
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    b.attachA(a);
    b.callDoSomethingFromIFace();
}
```

Comment: So this works, but I'm not clear on why. The difference is that the make_shared call is not made in the call to attachA.

This is the error I get using the wrong code:
`new_allocator.h:136:4: error: invalid new-expression of abstract class type ‘IFace’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~
main.cpp:4:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘IFace’:
 class IFace {
main.cpp:7:18: note:  virtual void IFace::doSomething()
     virtual void doSomething() = 0;`

Which made me believe it was because I did not construct it.

Comment: And how does the wrong code look like? Because`b.attachA(std::make_shared<A>());` would also work.

Comment: Ah yes, I made the silly mistake of passing the object a to make_shared which obviously does not expect to be called with an object. Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: @DJohnson If the constructor of `A` would have parameters, then you would pass arguments to the `std::make_shared` which would be forwarded to the the constructor of `A`. So `std::make_shared<A>(1, "foo")` would be equal to `new A(1, "foo")`.